# python com redis

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, redis

Boa noite,
Estou tentando fazer uma aplicação simples de mensagens que una Python com o Redis, consegui fazer a conexão com o banco em um set/get simples, porém não to conseguindo fazer nenhum hashe para salvar/buscar as mensagens ou usuários no redis nem os inputs estão funcionam. Estou usando VisualStudioCode com powershell para fazer. Alguém sabe como proceder?
Aqui vai o código --->

```
from cli import User
import redis
```

## Testa conexão com redis (aqui funciona)

```
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.set('fruta', 'pera')
True
r.get('fruta')
b'pera'

class Servidor(nick.User):
    def __init__(self, host = 'localhost', port = 6379,):
        self.__host = host
        self.__port = port
        self.__nick = nick
        self.__password = password

from chat import Servidor
import redis
import getpass
import datetime
```

## Testa conexão com redis

```
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r.set('fruta', 'manga')
True
r.get('fruta')
b'manga'

class User:
    def __init__(self, nick, password, msg, host = '127.0.0.1', port = 9999):
        self.__nick = nick
        self.__password = password
        self.__msg = msg
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
```

## Cria novo usuário

```
def new_user(self, nick, apelidos, host, port):
    r.hset.i = input('Digite seu apelido único: ')
    for nick in apelidos:
        apelidos:str = input('Apelido já escolhido, seja mais original e escolha outro')
```

## Define a senha de acesso

```
def escolha_senha(self, password):
    password = getpass.getpass (input('Digite sua senha: '))
    password2 = getpass.getpass (input('Digite novamente sua senha: '))
    if password == password2:
        password = r.hset
    else:
        return False
```

## Envia mensagem sem espaços para algum usuário (mas ainda não salva no redis)

```
def send(self, sender, msg):
    self.msg = r.hset(input(msg.strip()))
    self.sender = self.__nick
```

## Armazena mensagem em um hash

```
def storage_msg(self, msg, time):
    self.msg = r.hset
    self.time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    while msg != '/bye':
        msg = input(print("Envie sua mensagem: ",msg," - ",time))
```

Comment: Olha - alguem pode s desdobrar pra responde essa pergunta - mas você está tentando usar vários conceitos diferentes sem entender algumas coisas básicas antes - por exemplo, recriando uma variável do `for` dentro do próprio `for`, sua função `new_user` nunca tenha criar uma instância da classe  `user`, nem tem um `if` para testar se algo existe ou não - etc... bastante confusão mesmo. 
Tente clarear uma parte de cada vez, voltando na documentação ou curso por onde você está aprendendo - e talvez seja uma boa deixar o redis para um pouco depois: use um dicionário simples em Python até funcionar

Comment: Um conceito bacana: `input` é uma função legal para pegar entrada de dados, mas ela _para_ o programa, e impede qualquer tipo de teste unitário. Separe a lógica de seu programa de forma que as funções de verificação/conexão _nunca_ tenham uma chamada a `input`, e sim, recebam o valor que o usuário vai entrar como um parâmetro. Aí você escreve outras funções que fazem a parte de "print/input" e chamam as primeiras.

Comment: Outra coisa - Python não tem atributos "privados" - alguma documentaçao mais antiga confunde os dos `__` de prefixo com atributos privados - desconsidere isso, e não use - isso só torna o código mais difícil de ler e lidar com, no estágio em que você está de se familiarizar com a linguagem.